# YOLOV8: how to save the output of model

Tags: python, yolo, yolov8, yolov7

this is the code

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
license_plate_detector = YOLO('./model/best.pt')
license_plates = license_plate_detector('./42.jpg')
```

and this the output

```
640x608 1 number-plate, 342.0ms
Speed: 12.4ms preprocess, 342.0ms inference, 3.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 608)
```

i want to convert this output to image and save it to use with esayocr

the class don't have any save method so how to do this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it will helps you.

```
from PIL import Image
from ultralytics import YOLO
import easyocr

license_plate_detector = YOLO('./model/best.pt')

input_image = Image.open('./42.jpg')

detections = license_plate_detector(input_image)

license_plate_boxes = detections[0].boxes.data.cpu().numpy()

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])

for i, box in enumerate(license_plate_boxes):
    x1, y1, x2, y2, conf, cls = box
    license_plate = input_image.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))
    
    plate_filename = f'license_plate_{i}.jpg'
    license_plate.save(plate_filename)

    results = reader.readtext(plate_filename)
    print(f"License Plate {i+1} Text: {results[0][1]}")
```

Comment: thank you put i don't work show this error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 11
      7 input_image = Image.open('./42.jpg')
      9 detections = license_plate_detector(input_image)
---> 11 license_plate_boxes = detections.xyxy[0].cpu().numpy()
     13 reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
     15 for i, box in enumerate(license_plate_boxes):

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xyxy'

Comment: Try it with a small adjustment: ```license_plate_boxes = detections[0].boxes.data.cpu().numpy()```

Comment: don't work and show this error "name": "AttributeError",
 "message": "module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'",

Comment: update the PIL library using pip

Comment: update it and the same error appear again

Answer (score 1):

To save the detected objects as cropped images, add the argument `save_crop=True` to the inference command. To save the original image with plotted boxes on it, use the argument `save=True`. The results will be saved to 'runs/detect/predict' or a similar folder (the exact path will be shown in the output).

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
license_plate_detector = YOLO('./model/best.pt')
license_plates = license_plate_detector('./42.jpg', save=True, save_crop=True)
```

You can specify where to save the output data using the parameters for project name `project` and experiment name `name`. To save all experiment results in the same folder use `exist_ok=True`.

```
license_plates = license_plate_detector('./42.jpg', save=True, save_crop=True, project="runs/detect", name="inference", exist_ok=True)
# runs/detect/inference
```

More information about inference: https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#inference-arguments

Comment: thanks, it's working put each time I run the code it creates a new predict folder with numbers for example predict1 predict2...

Comment: Use the parameter exist_ok=True to avoid this behavior. I have added this to the answer